# Maven war contains extra dependencies if not built standalone

Tags: java, dependencies, maven, war, ear

I've got a war which I'm trying to reduce the dependencies contained in it's WEB-INF/lib as they're provided by the ear and if they're only in the ear it resolves some classloader issues I've had.

If I run mvn clean install in the module for the war it builds in only the dependencies I want. If I go up a level and run mvn install on the project (the war's defined as a module in the pom.xml at this level) then the war is repackaged with a *lot* more dependencies.

Why would the behaviour be different and how can I stop all these extra dependencies getting in?

I've tried following the advice here but saw no difference in the behaviour: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html

Maven 2.0.6, maven-ear-plugin 2.4.1, maven-war-plugin 2.1-beta-1 (I can't change the versions, I'm on a closed network). Thanks in advance.

ETA: A mvn clean install at the project level gives me the results I want. An mvn clean and then an mvn install adds in the extra jars that I don't want.

Comment: How does your project structure look like? POM snippets ?

Comment: Parent pom.xml contains a module tag for the war module and the ear module. The ear pom.xml contains a webModule tag for the war and a dependency tag too.

Answer (score 2):

Run `mvn dependency:tree` to see where the (probably transitive) dependencies are coming in from.

You'll want to read "Maven the Definitive Guide" (free PDF by Sonatype) in order to get an in depth understanding of how Maven deals with Dependency management.

And *please* do find a way to upgrade to maven 2.1.0 (preferably 2.2.1), and the latest versions of the plugins, earlier versions are notoriously buggy.

Comment: I'll try and get hold of the PDF, thanks. The dependency tree shows me the entire list of all dependencies, which are almost all marked as provided. The few I want are scoped as compile, with a few others as test and end up in the war's lib when building the module. But all the others end up in there when building the project. I'm not sure the tree tells me anything more than I already know.

Comment: Did you run mvn dependency:tree at the ear project level or at the parent level?

Comment: Parent and war level. The output appears to be the same.

Comment: What happens when you build at the ear level?